# Maven Java version without using maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to specify the version of Java that Maven uses without editing the pom.xml and adding the `maven-compile-plugin`?  My JAVA_HOME is pointing to version 1.7, but Maven is trying to compile my project with Java 1.3 for some reason, even though that version of Java isn't even installed on the system.

Comment: I don't understand how my question is a duplicate when I specifically asked for a solution without using the plugin, and the question that you marked this a duplicate of asks for a solution with the plugin.  Is that not possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that actually?

Comment: Because I don't own the project, but am trying to configure a Jenkins job for the project.  So, I don't want to edit the project's pom and commit it to SVN in case it breaks anything (although I doubt it will).  I am only a junior developer and these orders are coming from higher up...

Comment: That's an unreasonable fear. First of all you're going to test it before you commit, and second of all if anything breaks, the world does not end. You just change it back. Jenkins was not invented so people fear the fact that they'll be easily confronted with making mistakes. But no, you can't do this without making changes to the pom.

Comment: I used Maven 3.3.1 instead of Maven 2.2.1 and it worked without the maven-compiler-plugin.